# hibernate one to many bidirectional association is not deleting child object

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

I try to update parent object with deleted child object. It passes successfully, however next load returns deleted object again. It is one to many bidirectional relationship. I am not sure how to deal with update once i have parent object.

Comment: It would be a good idea to show the relevant mapping files (pruned down would be good), along with the code you are using to remove the child from the parent. I'm a big Struts2 fan, but I've edited the question to remove reference to it and the client side concerns because it distracts from the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

We'll probably need you to provide more details, but typically, one-to-many relationships are mapped with `@OneToMany(..., orphanRemoval = true)` and removing a child looks like:

```
// session opened, transaction begun
Parent p = session.load(Parent.class, 1234);
p.getChildren().remove(child);
// transaction committed, session closed
```

See the [discussion of one-to-many parent/child relationships](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html) in the Hibernate reference guide.